# finding the original posts in a forest like structure using id and parent_id

Tags: python, networkx

I have a DataFrame containing both posts and comments.
I want to map each comment to its original post using the "id" and "parent_id" columns. "id" = unique identifier for each post or comment
"parent_id" = the id of the post or comment to which it is a reply.
The "parent_id" column is always empty for posts, as posts are not replying to anything.
I would like to create a new column called "ancestor_id" which stores the id of the original post.

I have this code that works for the test dataset created in the code, but not on actual one.
In the actual one, the "ancestor_id" value for comments is always equal to "parent_id"

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "parent_id": [None, 1, 1, 3, 4],
    "text": ["Post 1", "Comment 1.1", "Comment 1.2", "Comment 3.1", "Comment 4.1"]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a directed graph using NetworkX
G = nx.DiGraph()

# Add nodes (posts and comments) to the graph
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    G.add_node(row["id"])
    if not pd.isna(row["parent_id"]):
        G.add_edge(row["parent_id"], row["id"])

# Find the ancestors (original posts) using NetworkX's ancestors method
ancestor_dict = {}

for node in G.nodes:
    ancestors = nx.ancestors(G, node)
    if ancestors:
        ancestor = min(ancestors)  # Find the earliest ancestor
        ancestor_dict[node] = ancestor
    else:
        ancestor_dict[node] = node  # If there are no ancestors, it's a post itself

# Create the "ancestor_id" column using the dictionary
df["ancestor_id"] = df["id"].map(ancestor_dict)

# Display the resulting DataFrame
print(df)
```

If use G.pred["k7b1uj7"] it gives me only its parent_id. If I use this parent_id in the same line of code, I can get the "granfather", so is not that there is only one node.

How can I possibly fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `networkx`'s [`weakly_connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.weakly_connected_components.html):

```
# create graph from the DataFrame
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df.dropna(subset=['id', 'parent_id'])
                              .convert_dtypes(),
                            create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                            source='parent_id', target='id')

# find roots
roots = {n for n,d in G.in_degree() if d==0}
# {1}

mapper = {}
# for each subgraph, get the (supposedly unique) root
# assign to each node
for g in nx.weakly_connected_components(G):
    root = next(iter(g & roots))
    for n in g:
        mapper[n] = root

# map the roots
df['ancestor_id'] = df['id'].map(mapper)
```

Output:

```
   id  parent_id         text  ancestor_id
0   1        NaN       Post 1            1
1   2        1.0  Comment 1.1            1
2   3        1.0  Comment 1.2            1
3   4        3.0  Comment 3.1            1
4   5        4.0  Comment 4.1            1
```